# Strange language problem with Android Studio, how to change default locale?

Tags: android, android-studio, locale

I'm in the UK, I've created a strings.xml and different graphics for the US English speakers as they call animals by a different name and they spell things differently. I've noticed when creating my app the default in Android Studio is "en-us", how do I change this?

[image: showing the AS settings]

Now, the issue I am having is:
Our phones are set to English (United Kingdom)
They are showing the default images (not the "drawable-en_rUS" ones - USA)
But showing the "strings-en-rUS" strings rather than the default strings.

I've copied the default strings into a generic English folder ("strings-en" & drawable-en), but then in Android Studio if I choose "English(en)" from the drop down, it shows the US images and strings rather than the ones in the "-en" folders. 
Clicking "Default(en-us)" in Android Studio then shows all the defaults (UK English).

Really confused by this, I'm assuming there should be a way to set Android Studio to "en-uk" but I cannot find it or anything online to help me. I'm wanting the defaults to be the main one so any other English speakers get the non-US spellings and words.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: you want string localization for different languages?

Comment: I have, I have the default (English) which is strings.xml in strings folder and the graphics in drawable, I then have US English strings.xml in strings-en-rUS and graphics in drawable-en-rUS

I'm wanting the default to be English, then US only to see the US strings and graphics. However, we are in the UK and it shows us default graphics with US strings. Android Studio says "Default (en-us)" at the top and I assume that might be something to do with it?

I've tried creating strings-en and drawable-en too, for all other English speakers that aren't US, but that doesn't work either

Comment: Sir why you're looking on xml layout as, the layout shows localization that defined in default string file. you can implement the localization routing in java code. lemme share the code if you want

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. The problem is when we have it on our phones for testing, it shows the incorrect strings.xml (shows us US rather than the default) but the correct (default) graphics when our phones are set to "English (United Kingdom)". If I copy the default strings and graphics to a generic English folder (strings-en and drawable-en) our phones then show the US graphics and strings rather than the new "-en" ones. Also, I'm using Kotlin (not Java)

Comment: If it's only Android Studio related and compiled app running fine, why does that bother you so much? You can use en-us as default and it won't affect your app. Similar, Android Studio's gui is en-us, not gb I guess. Shown resources will always match locale set on phone, if you want to change that behavior, there is many tutorials how to do that

Comment: the complied app isn't fine, that's what I'm saying, we have our phones set to English (United Kingdom) and it's showing generic graphics (UK) but US strings. The generic strings (UK) needs to be the default for everywhere that speaks English except for the US.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm currently having the same problem, although I'm not in the US and the phone's locale is set to English (UK) I get the resources from `values-en-rUS`

Answer (score 1):

Means, you want generic strings (UK) needs to be the default for everywhere that speaks English except for the US.

Copy all (**UK**) string in default string file and copy all (**US**) string to **values-en-rUS** directory and implement this code maybe it'll help you:

```
if(Locale.getDefault().country.equals("US")) {
        val locale = Locale("en", "US")
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
    }
```

Use this code in start of the app, **Application** class might be best for it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go tonight